# Set Content of an Element without a Name-Property

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using a ListBox in combination with a ObservableCollection. The content is set via a TemplateSelector (TextBlock or Label). The text has to be formatted (f.e. with Run-Tags in Code-behind), but i can't access the Items. Is there a solution to get the elements?

I've tried the usage of OfType<>, but this works only on Panels. I searched for an children-attribute but, there isn't one for ListBoxes. Setting the Name-Property via binding is not possible for UId and Name.
An IEnumerator for the LogicalChildren doesn't work and iterate over the whole content everytime a new element is added, is not so optimal. Here a minimal example.

```
<Window.Resources>
     <DataTemplate x:Key="TextBlockTemplate">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

     <DataTemplate x:Key="LabelTemplate">
        <StackPanel>
            <Label/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

    <local:myTemplateSelector x:Key="myTemplateSelector" x:Name="myTemplateSelector" TextBlockTemplate="{StaticResource TextBlockTemplate}" LabelTemplate="{StaticResource LabelTemplate}"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid Margin="0">
    <ListBox Name="mylist" Grid.Row="3" 
             ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
             ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"  
             ItemsSource="{Binding _listEntries}"                 
             ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource myTemplateSelector}"
             >
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Greetings and thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, I found a solution. I made the TextBlock and Label as User Control and set the Name-property. In the code-behind, I have access to the DataContext and the element can set itself.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test.TextBlockControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TextBlockControl"
         Loaded="UserControl_Loaded">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Margin="0,0,0,0">
        <TextBlock Name="textBlock"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

In the Code behind i can now access the values and set:

```
    public partial class TextBlockControl : UserControl
{
    public List<string> name => DataContext as List<string>;

    public TextBlockControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            foreach (var t in name)
            {
                var run = new Run(t.Text);
                if (t.IsHighlighted)
                {
                    run.Foreground = Brushes.Green;
                }
                else
                {
                    run.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
                }
                textBlock.Inlines.Add(run);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the MainWindow, the dataTemplate then references the UserControl (root is the namespace):

```
<root:PickControl />
```

Answer (score 0):

The `TextBlock` has an [Inlines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.textblock.inlines?view=netframework-4.8) property that returns the `Inline` elements that comprise the contents of the `TextBlock`.

The `Label` has a `Content` property that you, depending on how you are using it, may cast to a `Panel`.

There are no inline elements for a `TextBox`.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. But I don't have access to the Labels/TextBlocks because i can't reference it without a name :)

Comment: Where do you want to access them?

Comment: In the MainWindow.xaml.cs ;)
I found a solution and postet it.